# Fetching random rows using a random index and RAND( )

Tags: mysql, random

I'm using the following code to return a random row from a table. Using the field 'rand'.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  imgs
WHERE rand > RAND( ) 
ORDER BY rand ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

The field 'rand' is generated by mysql at creation using something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO imgs SET rand = RAND ()
```

For some reason the results although changing each run are only rows with a very low 'rand' field. There is definitely a complete range with over 7,000 rows. Seams to work fine if i replace the 'WHERE rand > RAND( )' with 'WHERE rand > [a number between 0-1]'

Comment: Aside from that it doesn't scale well when dealing with 100K+ rows, why not just use `ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: Am trying to develop a very optimized system for a client whose need regularly push my shared server to the limit.
The obvious solution would be to generate the random float in php, however seams more logical to do it in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

`RAND()` generates a floating point value x where 0 <= x < 1.0... to generate a larger number (whole number) use `FLOOR(y + (RAND() * z))` which will generate a value x where y <= x < (y+z)

Comment: I know. The problem is for some reason in the context of 'WHERE' it does not seam to be correctly generating a floating point number between 0-1. RAND () is used to generate the column at the insert stage